# I have vector of indexes. How to set ones at given index in each row?

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave

I have a vector `y` with integer values from 1 to 10:

```
octave> size(y)
ans =

   5000      1
```

I created `zeros` array `y1`:

```
octave> size(y1)
ans =

   5000     10
```

I need to set `1` in each row of `y2`, in the element with index equal to value in `y`. So in first row, when I have:

```
octave> y(1)
ans =  10
```

I need to have:

```
octave> y1(1,:)
ans =

   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

Something reverse to `[w, y] = max(y2, [], 2);` I have in other places of my code.

Is there a simple one-line trick to do that? And if not, how can I iterate over both arrays simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you mean to do this in `y1` or `y2`. In any case, try this (on `y1` for example):

```
y = randi(10,5000,1);
y1 = zeros(size(y,1), 10);
y1(sub2ind(size(y1), (1:size(y1,1))', y)) = 1;
```

Comment: error: sub2ind: all subscripts must be of the same size | 
error: evaluating argument list element number 1 | 
error: invalid empty index list

Comment: I added the `zeros` beforehand. Was this what was missing?

Comment: Nope - that's how I created y2 myself. It was there, it has size posted in my question - exactly the same size your command created.

Comment: Got it. It was a missing transpose :)

Answer (score 11):

You can use this trick

```
y1 = eye(10)(y,:);
```

or it's two-step version

```
y1 = eye(10);
y1 = y1(y,:);
```

### Explanation

In first step you create a identity matrix

```
  >> y1 = eye(10)    

    y1 =    

 Diagonal Matrix

       1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
       0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
       0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
       0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

In the second step you use `y` as index in the indentity matrix. This step literally copy rowsfrom identity matrix and create desired matrix.

```
>> y = [1,1,2,2,5,10,10];
>> y1 = y1(y,:)
y1 =

   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know a one line trick but you can do it in a one simple loop:

```
for i=1:length(y)
     y1(i,y(i))=1;
end
```

Comment: Easier to understand than the other answer and works just as well, but sadly - way slower over thousands of elements